# Mousedown event is not fired in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have a very annoying problem.
In Chrome and Firefox both last version the mousedown event is not fired.
IE 11 works fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/CyzT8/

Later I would like add and remove widgets, so I can't use the working extract.

```
        // DOES NOT WORK in Chrome and Firefox
        //$("#content_wrapper").mousedown(".resizer", function (e) {
        //    e.preventDefault();
        //    resizing = true;
        //    frame = $(this).parent();
        //});

        // DOES work in all browsers
        $(".resizer").mousedown(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            resizing = true;
            frame = $(this).parent();
        });
```

Comment: codes after e.preventDefault() will not be executed.

Comment: Your second commented out event handler [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/CyzT8/6/) in Chrome and Firefox nightly. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Use [jQuery's `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for event delegation. [`mousedown()`, according to the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/), apparently doesn't shorthand it.

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion.  If you ever want anyone to be able to drag them increase the black section to more than 2 pixels. It's annoying. haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can pass the selector in this way on a `.mousedown()` event. See the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/. So the following just won't work:

```
$("#content_wrapper").mousedown(".resizer", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    resizing = true;
    frame = $(this).parent();
});
```

Within your fiddle, the second one works fine for me in Chrome and I believe is correct.

```
$("#content_wrapper").on("mousedown", ".resizer", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    resizing = true;
    frame = $(this).parent();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#content_wrapper").mousedown(".resizer", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   resizing = true;
   frame = $(e.target).parent();
});
```